# How do I position a div 'x' pixels from the center of a page?

Tags: html, position, center, pixel

I want to position a `<div>` a given number of pixels relative to the center of a page. How can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `$(window).width() / 2` to get the horizontal center... like:

```
$('.myDiv').css({left: ($(window).width() / 2) - 50})
```

You'll get the `div` `50px` left of the center

Comment: Isn't there a pure CSS solution?

Comment: Yes, but only with vendor specific prefix, and it's not compatible with older browsers... ex.:
    margin-left: -webkit-calc(50% - 250px)

Comment: Alright, that works. I'm surprised that IE supports it, and that Opera doesn't.