# CSS positioning to center plus x pixel

Tags: jquery, html, css

Is there any way to use only `CSS` to positioning center plus x pixel a `div`?

I have now this CSS codes:

```
#mydiv {
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 200px auto;
}
```

I want to position this div to center + 300px to right. It is possible to do using only CSS?

(I know [here is a way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11905699/how-do-i-position-a-div-x-pixels-from-the-center-of-a-page) to using jQuery, but I want to do using only CSS.)

Comment: Can you elaborate your question?
On a side note, maybe css calc can help you :
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc

Comment: Is IE support an important thing for you? There are several solutions to this problem using CSS3 (transform, calc...), but they won't work in a bit older browsers. I provided my answer below in case you want wider browsers support without using CSS3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could achieve this by adding `transform: translateX(300px);` to `#mydiv`.

**Take a look on JSFiddle  [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/asmyupj5/)**

```
#mydiv {
    display: block; 
    width: 200px; 
    margin: 200px auto; 
    transform: translateX(300px); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is, for browsers that support CSS3 [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc).

```
#mydiv {
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
    margin-left: calc(50% + 200px); /* 50% - 100px (half of the div) + 300px */
}
```

```css
    #mydiv {
      display: block;
      width: 200px; height: 50px;
      margin-left: calc(50% + 200px);
      /* 50% - 100px (half of the div) + 300px */
      background: blue;
    }
```

```html
<div id="mydiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, check the <kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ronency/02cgvzy8/1/)</kbd>

It is possible without using any CSS3 tricks, if you can adjust your HTML a bit. The trick is to position a `.wrapper` element, with size of 0X0 px in the center of the screen (on the `.container` in this example), and INSIDE this wrapper you can position your `.content` and play with its 'offset' (the `right`/ `left` properties).
Hope it helps :-)

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="anchor">
        <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
    background-color:red;
    position:relative;
    height:500px;
}
.anchor {
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    width:0;
    height:0;
    overflow:visible;
}
.content{
    position:absolute;
    right:-100px; /* play with this to shift the content from the center... */
    width:200px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this example: https://jsfiddle.net/j6rnvdzp/?

```
div {
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 200px auto;
    background-color:red;
    position:absolute;
    right:-300px;
        left:0;
}
```